# Фразеологические аналоги крушения и самообмана

Tags: фразеология, семантика, синонимы

1. Каким фразеологизмом можно выразить мысль о том, что человек принимает одно (плохое, некачественное) за другое (хорошее, высоко полезное и т. д.)?
2. И еще: какими фразеологическими оборотами выражают крушение, падение чего-либо (может быть, абстрактного, как идеи или принципы; что-то вроде "потерпеть крушение", "разлететься на кусочки")?

Приведите, пожалуйста, какое-то количество примеров из каждой группы.

Comment: Задайте 2 вопроса, а не один.

Answer (score 1):

Фразеологизмы, синонимичные "самообману", есть, они чаще всего выражают идею о том, что человек заблуждался: какое-то время он ожидал чего-то хорошего (от своих или чужих действий, обстоятельств), но по итогу всё оказалось плохо (действия принесли вред, или обстоятельства на самом деле были не такими уж хорошими). Вот несколько примеров.

1. **Видеть в розовом цвете (свете)** / **смотреть сквозь розовые очки** — идеализировать кого-либо или что-либо, не замечать недостатков, тёмных сторон кого-либо или чего-либо (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5+%28%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%29+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C+%28%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B8+%D1%82.+%D0%BF.%29+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)).
2. **Принимать желаемое за действительное** — заблуждаться по поводу чего-либо или кого-либо (см. [здесь](https://all_words.academic.ru/22194/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5)).
3. **Медвежья услуга** — услуга, повлёкшая, в конечном счёте, за собой негативные последствия для того, кому она была оказана. (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%8C%D1%8F+%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0)).
4. **Федот, да не тот** — о том, кто на самом деле хуже того, за кого его принимают или за кого он себя выдаёт (см. [здесь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/11249/%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82#:%7E:text=%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD,%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.)).

Фразеологизмы, синонимичные "крушению идей/принципов", найти сложнее. Гораздо больше фразеологизмов о смерти или исчезновении человека (**двинуть кони**, **кануть в Лету**, **сыграть в ящик**, **протянуть ласты**, **врезать дуба**, **скопытиться** и т. д.). Есть и фразеологизмы о разрушении (**камня на камне не оставить**, **разбить в пух и прах** и др.), но они больше о действии лица по уничтожению чего-либо, а не о фиаско абстрактных идей. Из того, что сумел отыскать, на мой взгляд, "крушению идей/принципов" соответствует разве что такое выражение, как "**пойти прахом**" (планы **пошли прахом**, мои принципы **рассыпались в прах** и т. п.). Впрочем, тут уже дело автора, как он хочет применить тот или иной фразеологизм.

1. **Пойти прахом** / **рассыпаться (разлететься) в прах** — погибнуть, уничтожиться (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8+%28%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%2C+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B8+%D1%82.+%D0%BF.%29+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC)).

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю, подойдёт ли вам? Дело в том, что по первому пункту в русском языке уже имеется слово - реснота (ударения на [а]). 
Реснота - не истина, вымысел, называемый истиной и  принимаемый за истину.